# How to Send Data From Pulse Sensor Wirelessly to GPIO Pins?

Tags: gpio, wireless, sensor

I am following this tutorial: https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-heartbeat-pulse-measuring/. But I would like to implement the sensor in a watch. Is there an accessory that can fit in my watch and link the sensor and the raspberry pi wirelessly with, whilst using the GPIO Pins.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to transfer fitness data such as heartrate from your fitness watch to your Raspberry Pi. Fitness watch vendors support this with software development kits (SDK). For example, here is the [FitBit Web API SDK](https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/)

With such a design you would not use GPIO, but would instead use the internet to access your watch data from the Raspberry Pi. NOTE: Implementing this would not be trivial.